# Looping through response variables in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am writing a JSP page that retrieves variables from a servlet and outputs them to the user, my current code works as follows :

```
String uploadStatus = (String) request.getAttribute("uploadStatus");
String readStatus = (String) request.getAttribute("readStatus");
String saveStatus = (String) request.getAttribute("saveStatus");
String completeStatus = (String) request.getAttribute("completeStatus");
String applicationName = (String) request.getAttribute("applicationName"); 
String buildAndroid = (String) request.getAttribute("buildAndroid"); 
String buildWindows = (String) request.getAttribute("buildWindows"); 
String buildiOS = (String) request.getAttribute("buildiOS");
String uploadCompleteStatus = (String) request.getAttribute("uploadCompleteStatus"); 
String startBuild = (String) request.getAttribute("startBuild"); 
String finishBuild = (String) request.getAttribute("finishBuild"); 

out.println(uploadStatus + "<br>");
out.println(readStatus + "<br>");
out.println(saveStatus + "<br>");
out.println(applicationName + "<br>");
out.println(buildAndroid + "<br>");
out.println(buildWindows + "<br>");
out.println(buildiOS + "<br>");
out.println(uploadCompleteStatus + "<br>");
out.println(startBuild + "<br>");
out.println(finishBuild + "<br>");
```

It works perfectly, but the code is lengthy and not very expnadable. I am wondering if their is a way to do this simpler in the JSP with a for loop and possibly a wildcard character. Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you add all status variables to a `List<String>` and add the `List` to a `request` attribute? This way you can use a single loop to output all variables.

```
List<String> statusItems = new ArrayList<>();
statusItems.add(uploadStatus);
statusItems.add(readStatus);
...
request.setAttribute("statusItems", statusItems);
```

BTW, the use of scriptlets in JSPs is discouraged. Use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/):

```
<c:forEach var="status" items="${requestScope.statusItems}">
  ${status} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Or use `<c:out value="${status}"/>` within `forEach` if you want your status values to be HTML-escaped.

Comment: Or just `${statusItems}`

Comment: I have never used JSTL, is it a library I have to download?

Comment: Yes, it is a tag library. Please refer this post for more information on JSTL:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Answer (score 3):

Make use the  `req.getAttributeNames()`

```
    Enumeration attrs =  req.getAttributeNames();
    while(attrs.hasMoreElements()) {
        String val = (String) req.getAttribute((String) attrs.nextElement());
        System.out.println(val);
    }
```

Comment: Java Code in JSP - No No!!

Comment: @RohitJain This code work's(Atleast helps) If OP wants to prepare  List in servlet and pass to the JSP.And NO NO to java code in JSP too :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure try this:

```
for (String lAttributeName : request.getAttributeNames()){
       System.out.println((String)request.getAttribute(lAttributeName));
}
```